# Inject Javascript to WebView won't work some times?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using a `WebView` to play some html5 animations and the animations depend on some `javascript` codes. I need to inject `javascript` codes into `WebView` before webpages loaded.

```
class AnimWebView extends WebView{
    getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    loadAnimation(String animUrl){
        //get javascript code
        String js_code = getMyJsCode();
        //inject the javascript code to WebView   
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js_code);
        //load animation
        mWebView.loadUrl(animUrl);
    }
}

AnimWebView animContainer = new AnimWebView(context);

// load first animation, the animation works fine.
animContainer.loadAnimation("file:///android_asset/animations/test1/index.html");

//after one minute load second animation(I omit the delay code.)
//it doesn't work because JS code can't be find.
animContainer.loadAnimation("file:///android_asset/animations/test2/index.html");
```

Because it works first second and failed the second time, so I think maybe I need clear code and cache after first time.

So I tried to `clearView()`, `stopLoading()`, `loadUrl("about:blank")`. But they all doesn't work.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: You need to add mWebView.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true)

Comment: Hi asgoth, I already added it, don't work. The core issue is the content in webview works fine first time but failed on second time.